# Are modals secure against XSS, SQL injection or other attacks?

Tags: discord, discord.js, xss

Discord lets us have the ability to create modals which are basically submission forms. Are the modals secure against attacks like XSS or SQL injections so that we don't need to sanitize user inputs anymore?

I've tried doing `<script>alert(1);</script>` on one of my modal fields and it didn't do anything, but I only tested that on the Discord app. I'm not sure if the result will change if it's done on the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Modals are a form of user input, Discord may indeed do some filtering of it yet it will not be guaranteed, if you are using user input in any of your database queries or on a web page connected to your application the information gathered from modals is still vulnerable to common injection attacks.

If you are worried about the sanitization, here is a good page from OWASP on input sanitization.
https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Input_Validation_Cheat_Sheet.html

Comment: Makes sense. But what about my bot's token will they be able to somehow get that data if they try XSS on a modal?

Comment: XSS is primarily a web vulnerability. It is unlikely that they are able to get your bot's token through this method. Unless for some reason your bot were to also host a web page on the same process.

Comment: You could add a function that runs for every message your bot sends and it scans each message for its own token. This would in turn hide it from any messages the bot outputs.

Comment: I see. But I guess it'll still be good practice to sanitize the input regardless?

Comment: Sure, it can't hurt.

Comment: If this answer helped you it's useful if you mark it as the answer so that anyone who comes across the post in the future can easily see that it has a solution!